# Java Robot Class KeyEvent

Tags: java, class, keyevent, awtrobot

Is there a way to write the line

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
```

that will allow an html 5 game running in safari to register a spacebar press as having occurred inside the game? (by inside the game, I mean have the game react as if "space" was physically pressed)

For example, I have realized that some KeyEvents only register as having fired when over top of certain elements. The code below will successfully register a spacebar-press event in the URL bar of safari:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

 public class SpaceBarPress {

    SpaceBarPress(){
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try{
            Robot r = new Robot();  //create instance of robot class
            r.mouseMove(600,323); //move cursor over top URL bar

            r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); //bring URL bar into focus
            r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); //fire spacebar event
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);

          }
          catch(AWTException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

However, when the same code is run overtop an html 5 game running in the browser, a spacebar event will not register inside the game. Whereas, pressing the physical spacebar will have an effect on the game.

Comment: Why click on the URL bar to focus a browser window? Why not click inside the actual browser's canvas?

Comment: @Skyler I don't have any problem focusing the browser. The problem arises when I try to fire the spacebar event. The spacebar event works when the URL bar is in focus but not when I focus on the html 5 game window running in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

the robot key events are executed way faster to b handled by the application. instead use delay of some ms say 40 in between press and release events

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); //fire spacebar event
r.delay(40);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
```